# Jest Babel Error: Test suite failed to run

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "js-stack",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "babel-node src",
        "test": "eslint src && flow && jest --coverage"
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "eslint": "^7.1.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0 || ^1.7.0",
        "flow-bin": "^0.126.1",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%"
    ]
}
```

Here's my .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react",
        "flow"
    ]
}
```

While it got me the error

```
Test suite failed to run

    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
In /Users/Codes/Javascript/js-stack/node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js
```

Could Someone tell me how to deal with it? I tried some solutions as they said but still get it! SO confused!!!! THX

Answer (score 0):

Remember having a problem similar to this before. have you tried getting rid of the .babelrc with babel.config.js ? This is how the file will look like

```
/* eslint-disable func-names */
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-flow'
  ];
  const plugins = [];

  api.cache(false);

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

Comment: It's the version problem. I solved it with @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/preset-flow and the responding .babelrc  file. It's tricky.  THX for your reply:)